# Get Token wih pure Javascript. Xhr Status == 0

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

I try to make a pure JavaScript authentication process without the help of **ADAL.JS**

To be sure that the problem doesn't come from `JQuery`, I used a `xhr` request.

I can easily get the code string from an `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` get request. The response contains my **code** string, that I can use in the `/token` request

Then, I try to call the `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` url, using the `POST` method.

The **fiddler response** is correct sending me my **JSON** Structure (containing my **bearer** token) but the `xhr` object is returning `readyState == 4` and `status == 0` (instead of `status==200`, I guess)

Here is the code I used to send my `POST` data (It's a Typescript script, by the way) :

```
var data = 'grant_type=authorization_code'
    + '&code=' + code
    + '&client_id=' + clientId
    + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent('passwordDEEDADAEDEADADADADA=')
    + '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');

xhr.onerror = (ev: ErrorEvent) => {
    console.log(ev.message);
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {

    var state = e;

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status === 304) {
            var jsonResult = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            var access_token = {
                token: jsonResult.access_token,
                expires_in: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 
                (jsonResult.expires_in - 300) * 1000)
            };

        } else {
            //reject(xhr);
        }
    }
};

xhr.send(data);
```

Well... It works as expected, at least in fiddler :)

But my xhr request returns a `xhr.readyState == 4` and a `xhr.status == 0` ... 
dealing to an error with no message.

I made some search on StackOverflow on thi strange `status == 0` behavior, but didn't find anything really concluant ...

Hope I was understandable (You know, french guys .. don't speak English so well :) )

Sébastien

Comment: Are you trying to do this for webapp? It is not a good idea to keep your client secret at javascript side.

Answer (score 2):

The AAD OAuth endpoints do not properly support CORS at the moment.  We've enabled javascript apps to get tokens using the implicit flow, as Dan has described.

Also, please note that you should not be using your client_secret in a browser-based application.  Client_secrets are meant for use in confidential clients that run server side and can protect the integrity of the secret.  If the above is running in a browser, then your client secret is exposed to the world, which has serious security implications.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. Thanks for the quick answer. I understand now why the Implicit Flow is enabled for this kind of scenario. Finally the client secret confidentiality is a good point too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll ask someone else to double check on my answer here, but ADAL.JS only supports the OAuth2.0 implicit flow.  This will get you back an access token (from the authorize endpoint).  I don't believe you'll get a code or that you need to use the token endpoint for this scenario.

We have some samples and blog posts that describe the use of ADAL.JS that should help you a little more.

High level info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx#BKMK_Spa
Sample (github): https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-DotNet
Blog (from Vittorio): http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan;
I Know Adal.js onlys support Implicit Flow.
That's why I said I work without ADAL.JS :)

That's a very strange behavior of xhr, because the POST request seems good and legit. I have the bearer token, when i look at the response in Fiddler (marked as 200)
But the xhr returns a 0 status in my javascript code ...